# Assembling a json object from an array

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to make this code shorter and more succinct? Thanks

My objective is to:

1. Take an array of objects (someArray)
2. Use `get()` to get one specific property of each of someArr's objects (which is also an object itself, as I am working with a json object)
3. And push this object to the 'tabs' array of the newly created object I am returning

   ```
   function (someArray) {
       var resultObj = {};
       resultObj.tabs = [];
       someArray.map(function (obj) {
           resultObj.tabs.push(obj.get());   // get() gets the dataValues (Sequelize)
       });
       return resultObj;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of pushing to an array outside of the map function, just return obj.get() in each callback and use the return value of the map call.